# "device is not defined" when using build.phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

In a phonegap app, device is defined if running through PhoneGap Desktop.  However, if it is built online through build.phonegap, then it is not defined.

In build.phonegap, under plugins, it shows that the core plugins defined in the config.xml file (e.g., ) are all there.  But any line that tries to access device gets a "device is not defined" error, whereas this error doesn't happen when using PhoneGap Desktop.

For PhoneGap Desktop, I found that the secret is to add a script reference to cordova.js.  But this doesn't work for build.phonegap, apparently.  I tried also adding a similar reference to phonegap.js, but with no results.

PS:  One other piece of information.  To debug further, I tried wrapping the code using device in an "if" block checking if the device is ready.  So, on PhoneGap Desktop, the deviceready event fired, but on build.phonegap, it's never ready.

```
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.readyNow = true;
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

...

if(app.readyNow) {
   //Code to use device object.  Fires with PhoneGap Desktop, not in PhoneGap Build
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer by comparing a Hello World application auto-generated by PhoneGap Desktop and one that was just slightly different but had the problem.  So the answer is to put the script reference to cordova.js in the body, underneath the HTML, rather than in the head, and make sure that there is no reference to phonegap.js.  (If there is a phonegap.js, it will complain about NPObject, whereas if cordova.js is in the head section, the device will never be ready.)  This solved my problem.